# Are tuples really immutable in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tuples, immutability

One question that I faced today, which actually tested the immutability of the tuples in Python:

> - **Interviewer**: Are tuples immutable in Python?
> - **Me**: Yes
> - **Interviewer**: So what does `print(t1)` here print?
>
>   ```
>   t1 = (4, 5)
>   t1 = t1 + (91, 10)
>   print(t1)
>   ```
> - **Me**: `(4, 5, 91, 10)`
> - **Interviewer**: How does immutability of tuple then define this behavior?
> - **Me**: It's got nothing to do with immutability, `t1` label is referring to a new tuple.
> - **Interviewer**:
>
>   ```
>   >>> t = (1, 2, [3, 4]) 
>   >>> t[2] += [5, 6]
>   ```
>
>   What will happen next?
> - **Me**: `TypeError` is raised
> - **Interviewer**: What will be the value of `t` be after that?
> - **Me**: `(1, 2, [3, 4])` or `(1, 2, [3, 4, 5, 6])` maybe, not sure
> - **Interviewer**: What made you think the value will change to `(1, 2, [3, 4, 5, 6])` and what will happen if I write
>
>   ```
>   >>> t[2] = t[2] + [5, 6]
>   ```
>
>   will `t2` still be `(1, 2, [3, 4, 5, 6])` after this operation?

Comment: Yes, tuples are immutable, but they can hold references to mutable objects.

Comment: Tuple as a container is immutable, that means you cannot remove or add items to it, but the items it contains can be mutated. Also read: [Why does `a_tuple[i] += [‘item’]` raise an exception when the addition works?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works)

Answer (score 3):

**Even though the tuples are immutable, the object inside it can be mutuable**

Since in `>>> t = (1, 2, [3, 4])` the list is mutable so you can change the list value with Augmented assignment. `+=` but then the exception is raised.

here the t[2] list is modified as you can see

```
t =(1,2,[3,4])
>>> id(t[2])
38073768
>>> t[2] += [5,6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> t[2]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> id(t[2])
38073768
```

As you can see the t[2] id never gets changed.

[image]

As for the second case: `t[2] = t[2] + [5,6]` - it creates a new list and then assign it to `t[2]`

```
>>> li = [1,2]
>>> id(li)
38036304
>>> li = li + [3,4]
>>> id(li)
38074368
>>> li += [5,6]
>>> id(li)
38074368
```

As you can see `List = list + []` is a new list with a different id. and as the tuple is immutable t[2] doesn't get assigned to a new object in the second case

Comment: 1. Tuples are **absolutely immutable**, but they can *contain (references to) mutable objects*. 2. This doesn't explain why `t[2] += [5, 6]` is different to `t[2] = t[2] + [5, 6]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I changed the phrase . By relative immutability i meant it can have mutable Objects

Comment: This still doesn't cover 2.

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated the answer