# Python: tuple with mutable items

Tags: python, tuples, immutability, mutable

As we know `tuple` is immutable. But at the same time it can contain mutable entities.

Say we have a next `tuple`:

```
x = (1, [1, 2])
```

Let's try to change first element:

```
x[0] = 10
----> 1 x[0] = 10
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Yep. It is no wonder. Absolutely expected behavior.

Let's try to append an element to list in our `tuple`:

```
>>> x[1].append(3)    
(1, [1, 2, 3])
```

No any errors since we mutate a mutable entity as a list. There is the same reference to list.

And now let's try to append via `+=`:

```
 x[1] += [4]
----> 1 x[1] += [4]
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

>>> x
>>> Out[49]: (1, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Although there is `TypeError` value of our list have changed. I am  a little bit confused.

What is the reason for such duality behavior?

Comment: `+=` creates a new list unlike append

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799300/are-tuples-really-immutable-in-python