# Type hints in namedtuple

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, namedtuple, python-dataclasses

Consider following piece of code:

```
from collections import namedtuple
point = namedtuple("Point", ("x:int", "y:int"))
```

The Code above is just a way to demonstrate as to what I am trying to achieve.
I would like to make `namedtuple` with type hints.

Do you know any elegant way how to achieve result as intended?

Comment: Also, starting with py3.7 you have the dataclass option:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Answer (score 328, accepted):

The preferred syntax for a typed namedtuple since Python 3.6 is

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Point(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int = 1  # Set default value

Point(3)  # -> Point(x=3, y=1)
```

Starting with Python 3.7, consider using a [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int = 1  # Set default value

Point(3)  # -> Point(x=3, y=1)
```

Comment: @JohnE; The OP specifically asked for named tuples. Yes, many use cases of named tuples will be better served by data classes. But to quote the excellent [Why not namedtuples](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/why.html#namedtuples): _If you want a tuple with names, by all means: go for a namedtuple_

Comment: Using dataclasses, it is not possible to deconstruct the resulting object like you could a Tuple

Comment: A tuple is immutable.  A dataclass is not (by default)  It does have the frozen flag which gets close to tuple's behaviour.  Just something to be aware of.

Comment: if dataclass works for you, you can go further and use [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) package to enforce type checking on runtime in elegant way.

Comment: Dataclasses aren't subscribable, and they neither are unpackable while iterating as named tuples do so I think they are far from being a perfect alternative.

Comment: this is effectively just adding types to an ordered dictionary. "Tuple" in "named tuple" suggests it should rely on a constant hashable immutable value.

Comment: Tuples are not always immutable (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799300/are-tuples-really-immutable-in-python).. I mean the references to the objects are immutable, but if a member of a tuple is mutable - you can mutate it. In fact, if you "try hard" you can change both NamedTUple and frozen dataclass. Therefore, I would suggest to pick the one that looks better or is available at your python version.

Answer (score 179):

You can use [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)

From the docs

> *Typed version* of `namedtuple`.

```
>>> import typing
>>> Point = typing.NamedTuple("Point", [('x', int), ('y', int)])
```

This is present only in Python 3.5 onwards

Comment: In newer versions you may declare NamedTuples as `Point = typing.NamedTuple("Point", x=int, y=int)`, which is much cleaner and shorter.

Comment: ^ Documentation, discussion, and examples floating around for this syntax is nearly non-existent. I only found it in [the cpython typing.py file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d7a5aca982def155a9255893cefcc1493c127c9c/Lib/typing.py#L2408). It states the syntax is available from 3.6+, and it's at least in the 3.7+ code. Though there doesn't seem to be a cleaner version of this for setting defaults adjacent to the member/type declaration.

Comment: ^^ While the keyword-argument syntax [mentioned by @MarkedasDuplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/122901087) still works (tested on Python 3.10.9 ```(tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6)```), it was removed from the docstrings in [pull 105287](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/105287/files#r1216987153) because according to the pull author, _"this way of creating ```NamedTuple```s **isn't** supported by any [known] type checker"_.

Answer (score 15):

Just to be fair, `NamedTuple` from `typing`:

```py
>>> from typing import NamedTuple
>>> class Point(NamedTuple):
...     x: int
...     y: int = 1  # Set default value
...
>>> Point(3)
Point(x=3, y=1)
```

equals to classic `namedtuple`:

```py
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> p = namedtuple('Point', 'x,y', defaults=(1, ))
>>> p.__annotations__ = {'x': int, 'y': int}
>>> p(3)
Point(x=3, y=1)
```

So, `NamedTuple` is just syntax sugar for `namedtuple`

Below, you can find a creating `NamedTuple` function from the source code of `python 3.10`. As we can see, it uses `collections.namedtuple` constructor and adds `__annotations__` from extracted types:

```py
def _make_nmtuple(name, types, module, defaults = ()):
    fields = [n for n, t in types]
    types = {n: _type_check(t, f"field {n} annotation must be a type")
             for n, t in types}
    nm_tpl = collections.namedtuple(name, fields,
                                    defaults=defaults, module=module)
    nm_tpl.__annotations__ = nm_tpl.__new__.__annotations__ = types
    return nm_tpl
```

Comment: Syntactic sugar is something the *parser* can replace with more fundamental syntax. `NamedTuple` is a bit more complicated than that, being a function that actually does something at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I know what it does do during runtime. It is extracting types and adds them to `__annotations__` attr of just created  `namedtuple` using constructor `collections.namedtuple`. I added that code to the answer for better understanding.

Comment: @mrvol Thanks for this. it really helped me understand what is actually happening, and that the resulting object is the same in both cases.