# How to type hint namedtuple in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Type hint can define the return type in Python, so when a function returns namedtuple type, then how to define it?

```py
def bar(func):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        return namedtuple('data', 'name user')(**func(*args, **kwargs))

    return update_wrapper(decorator, func)


@bar
def info() -> NamedTuple:
    return {'name': 'a1', 'user': 'b1'}
```

> Expected type 'NamedTuple', got Dict[str,str] instead

As you know, the function `info()` returns `Dict[str, str]`, but the decorator `@bar` changes it. Now the function `info()` returns a namedtuple object, so is there a way to indicate that the function `info()` returns a namedtupe object by type hint?

Comment: Do you know how to use namedtuples? And have you read the docs for [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I assume you get the error on the `info` method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hints in namedtuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269772/type-hints-in-namedtuple)

Answer (score 1):

NamedTuple instances are created via [collections.namedtuple()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.namedtuple) function.

Since you are interested in typing elements of namedtuple, you could create a custom type that inherits the typed version of NamedType (as mentioned by @jab) and use it in type hints as shown below.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class CustomType(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    user: str

def info() -> CustomType:
    return CustomType('a1', 'b1')
```

Comment: This is an informative answer, but the code shown doesn't match the context of the question. How does the decorator (`@bar`) fit into this... I'd like to know.

Comment: In the question, the error message corresponds to the type hint of `info()`.  I assumed `@bar` is part of OP's attempt to add type hint to `info()`.  If the assumption is correct, then `@bar` is not required.  If not, then OP should clarify the intended purpose of `@bar`.